# How to use gpload utility?

Tags: greenplum

I have YAML file below:

```
---
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
DATABASE: xxx
USER: xxx
HOST: xxx
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
   INPUT:
    - SOURCE:
         LOCAL_HOSTNAME: 
           - 192.168.0.21
         PORT: 8081
         FILE: 
           - /home/root/test_input.txt
    - COLUMNS:
           - age: int4
           - name: varchar
           - surname: varchar
    - FORMAT: text
    - DELIMITER: '|'
    - ERROR_LIMIT: 2
    - LOG_ERRORS: true
   OUTPUT:
    - TABLE: sf_dfs.test_gpload
    - MODE: INSERT
   PRELOAD:
    - REUSE_TABLES: true
```

But i recieve a error: error when connecting to gpfdist http://192.168.0.21:8081//home/root/test_input.txt, quit after 11 tries  (seg0 slice1 192.168.0.23:6000 pid=2021845)
encountered while running INSERT INTO

Maybe somebody have experience about this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a port issue. If the database is up then please rerun the job with different port. Ensure that firewall is not blocking this port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes. I forgot disable my firewall... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

Are you running gpload as root?  root generally does not have access permissions to the database.  It needs to be run as gpadmin or a superuser.

The input file is in /home/root.  If you are running as gpadmin, can gpadmin access this file?  Permissions on the file?

Finally, does the target table exist in the database (sf_dfs.test_gpload)?  Was it created and distributed across all segments?  The error would seem to indicate the table is not there.